# Erlang command test failed to write "coverlog"

Tags: testing, erlang, common-test

I'm running Common Test from the command line using:

```
$ run_test -pa ../ebin -spec test.spec.all
```

and got the following error. Why does the io:format() call get a badarg error?

```
Testing testdir2.bds1.ep_SUITE: Starting test, 3 test cases


ERROR: Could not write normal heading in coverlog.
CoverLog: <0.318.0>
Reason: {badarg,[{io,format,
                     [<0.318.0>,
                      "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN\">\n<!-- autogenerated by '~w'. -->\n<html>\n<head><title>Coverage results</title></head>\n<body bgcolor=\"white\" text=\"black\" link=\"blue\" vlink=\"purple\" alink=\"red\">",
                      [test_server_ctrl]],
                     []},
                 {test_server_ctrl,write_coverlog_header,1,
                                   [{file,"test_server_ctrl.erl"},
                                    {line,5731}]},
                 {test_server_ctrl,write_default_coverlog,1,
                                   [{file,"test_server_ctrl.erl"},
                                    {line,5803}]},
                 {test_server_ctrl,stop_extra_tools,1,
                                   [{file,"test_server_ctrl.erl"},
                                    {line,1464}]},
                 {test_server_ctrl,init_tester,9,
                                   [{file,"test_server_ctrl.erl"},
                                    {line,1403}]}]}
Suite testdir2.bds1.ep_SUITE was killed with reason {terminated,
                                                       [{io,format,
                                                         [<0.318.0>,
                                                          "<html><body>\n",[]],
                                                         []},
                                                        {test_server_ctrl,
                                                         write_default_coverlog, 
                                                         1,
                                                         [{file,
                                                           "test_server_ctrl.erl"},
                                                          {line,5803}]},
                                                        {test_server_ctrl,
                                                         stop_extra_tools,1,
                                                         [{file,
                                                           "test_server_ctrl.erl"},
                                                          {line,1464}]},
                                                        {test_server_ctrl,
                                                         init_tester,9,
                                                         [{file,
                                                           "test_server_ctrl.erl"},
                                                          {line,1403}]}]}
```

Comment: Are you sure the process `<0.318.0>` is still alive? To where is the format message being sent? Doing a `io:format` call by hand using those arguments, except for `<0.318.0>`, works.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have something like ~s in io:format pattern ?

Can you provide some code that actually has this io:format ?